# Can Azure track utm_source and utm_medium?

Tags: azure, utm

Repeat title: Can Azure track utm tags?

Here is some links for azure analytic:
[Usage analysis for web applications with Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-web-track-usage/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Azure has special service - **Application Insights**.
You can create it on Azure dashboard:
[image]

This service can't allow track UTM tags , but you can create a custom events, where you can track this tags.
[Here is the guide for do that.](https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/)